# Change function in function

Tags: javascript, function

I have ready code something like this and 
**I can't change function Foo() because it's alias framework.**

```
  function Foo(){
    this.prop = {
      width: 200
    }
    this.do = function(s1,s2){
      alert(s1+s2);
    }
  }
```

I need change *do* function.

After *function Foo()* and before *var foo1 = new Foo(); foo1.do(1,0);* I try write

```
Foo.do = function(){
  alert('changed');            
}
```

I can't change *do* function. I used defineProperty and even constructor) I haven't prototype.

Full uncorrect demo code

```
function Foo(){
        this.prop = {
          width: 200
        }
        this.do = function(s1,s2){
          alert(s1+s2);
        }
}

      Foo.do = function(){
        alert('changed');
      }

      var foo1 = new Foo();
      foo1.do(1,0);
      var foo2 = new Foo();
      foo2.do(1,1);
      var foo3 = new Foo();
      foo3.do(1,2);
```

I can change it for foo1, foo2 and etc. I need cange it ine time.

Comment: You would need to change all of the instances from foo if you want to change the `.do` function. Or use prototypes.

Comment: what do you mean by I need cange it ine time???

Comment: Why can't you just completely overwrite Foo? since .do is being defined in the constructor, the only place where you can override it is either on each instance after it is instantiated, or inside said constructor that you "can't change".

Comment: I can't change function Foo() because it's alias framework.

Comment: Could you extend it instead? Create your own constructor that has all of foo's instance methods/properties, with a new `do` method?

Comment: Yes, of course. But Foo() function has over 2000 lines. And I need change 2 lines. That is why I wish to know it. If I can't do it I will return my another way: I changed long prototype which call do from Foo.))

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating your own constructor that implements Foo.

```js
function Foo() {
    this.prop = {
        width: 200
    }
    this.do = function (s1, s2) {
        console.log(s1 + s2);
    }
}
Foo.prototype.someMethod = function () {};

// can't change any of the above..

function MyFoo() {
    Foo.call(this);
    this.oldDo = this.do;
    this.do = function (s1, s2, s3) {
        // do something else!
        console.log(s1 + s2 + s3);
    }
}
MyFoo.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);

// tests...
var foo = new Foo();
foo.do(2, 2, 2); // 4
console.log(foo.prop.width); // 200
var myFoo = new MyFoo();
myFoo.do(2, 2, 2); //6
console.log(myFoo.prop.width); // 200
```

Your new constructor only has to override the methods you want to change, the rest will stay the same and the original isn't changed. Notice how instances of MyFoo also have a .prop property even though that was done in Foo's constructor, not MyFoo.

Answer (score 0):

```
newDo = function(){}; // your new do function    
var foo1 = new Foo()'
foo1.do = newDo;
foo1.do(1,0)
```

and so on. If you can't change the `Foo` function, and you can't restrict yourself to ES6 or Firefox (they have ways to modify the prototype), then the best option is to overwrite `do` after creating a `new Foo`.

This is also a good point to plug learning the module pattern so that you can create your own nested versions of things:

```
function Foo() {}; //your original foo
(function() {
  function Foo() {}; //your new foo with a new do method
  // do stuff with the modified do here
})()
```